# How to provide access to like or comment news feed for visitors group in sharepoint 2013?

Tags: 2013, permissions

I have Newsfeed in my SharePoint 2013 site, I gave read access to this site but minimum permission to respond to the newsfeed is contribute. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to stop inheriting permission in the NewsFeed list and provide contribute access for all visitors to that list. [This](http://www.n8d.at/blog/allow-users-with-view-permission-add-entries-to-the-newsfeed/) might give you an idea for the same.

Comment: What if you just want to enable "Likes", not comments?